# How do I use an LEDs wired for 277V AC on a 12V DC power supply?

Tags: led, ac, dc

I have some LEDs that I am trying to re-purpose.  They were originally running on 277V AC.

The LEDS are soldiered onto a pretty large board with just two wires coming out.  If I measure the voltage coming from this board it is around 240 volts DC.

The 277V AC goes into this board and 240 DC is coming out.
[image: board]

Can someone explain what I need to purchase make these light up from a Car battery?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the obvious option is an inverter. Also, 277V? That's an unusual one! Is this meant to run off an industrial 480V three-phase supply?

Comment: The simplest solution is use an car inverter from 12V DC to 240V AC. But since they expect 277V that may not work. You could replace the Power board with your own design,  but that's a significant amount of engineering work.

Comment: Yes it is from a warehouse.  I was hoping there was some 12V DC to 240V DC option that did not require me going to 277V AC first.

Comment: It would probably help if I understood why the LEDs are taking 240V DC

Comment: It's easier to handle higher voltage than it is higher current. By wiring the leds in series, they can power this with just 100mA instead of 4V * 8 Amps.

Comment: So if I found a 240V DC power supply I could just hook it to these LEDs? or would I need some kind of resistor too?  There is nothing but LEDs on the LED board.  And no other boards other than this one pictured.

Comment: Good luck « just finding » a 240vdc power supply...

Comment: This board takes the Power, recertified it to dc, then uses a feedback sense network to limit the current to probably 100mA. The output voltage can vary. You wouldn't use just a resistor for current control in this setup. But I'm sure you can find a set up led driver that handles that current and voltage. But cost/ time etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Measure the input AC voltage.  I doubt the input must be 277VAC.  Many LED drivers specify an input voltage from 100VAC to 277VAC.  277VAC is associated with a commercial electrical service of 3 phase 480/277 where the 277 can be used single phase.

The voltage of a constant current driver will adapt to the forward voltage (V<sub>f</sub>)  of the LEDs being driven.If there were 80 LEDs each with a V<sub>f</sub> of 3.0V, the output would then be 240V.

A 12V inverter may work fine.  IF you measure 277VAC at the input then try using 120/240VAC before buying an inverter.

Keep in mind you may be able to use an inexpensive DC-DC LED driver that may likely cost less than an inverter. Although 240V is too high for the common solutions.

Comment: 277V single phase is very common in warehouse, office, and commercial/industrial lighting. While some lights will work on multiple voltages, there are plenty that are 277VAC only.

Comment: Its close to 277.  The fixture comes from a warehouse. I've tried 120 and it did not work. I haven't tried 240 and I will.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that they are 80 LED in series.  Maybe I can cut the board into smaller sections and reconnect them in a different arraignment.